# Using regular expressions to grab initial letters of string while preserving punctuation and white space

Tags: java, regex, string

Take the following Java string:

```
"Hello, World"
```

I want to take that string and turn it into:

```
"H, W"
```

There are [java utilities](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html) that will turn it into "HW", but I want to preserve the white space and punctuation.  I can do this by splitting the string and processing each word individually, but that is too slow.  I'm trying to find a regular expression where I can grab all letters of a word but the first?  I.e, grab "ello" and "orld" and replace them with "".  I know that "\w" will grab all letters, but is there a way to exclude the first letters of each word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The capture sequence would look something like:

```
(\\w)\\w*
```

And the replace like:

```
$1
```

The idea is you want to capture the first character as its own group, and simply consume as many extra word characters as possible.