# Extract first letter, white space and punctuation in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract the first letter of every word, the white space and punctuation in a given input.

> "Hello, World"

will produce

> "H, W"

Here's a Java example of this, but I'd like this in PHP:

[Using regular expressions to grab initial letters of string while preserving punctuation and white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764766/using-regular-expressions-to-grab-initial-letters-of-string-while-preserving-pun)

Comment: you already have the regular expression needed from the question you linked to... you can use that in php, see http://us1.php.net/preg_match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$arrays = $result = array();
$string = 'Hello, World';

$arrays = array_merge($arrays, explode(', ', $string));
foreach($arrays as $value){
$result[] = trim( preg_replace( "/[^0-9a-z]+/i", "", substr($value, 0, 1) ) );

}
$string = implode (", ", $result);
echo $string;
```

This code will work, but i'm not sure about removing whitespaces & puncutations

```
$result[] = trim( preg_replace( "/[^0-9a-z]+/i", " ", substr($value, 0, 1) ) );
```

replace above line from code to your solution to whitespaces & punctuations.

or this line replacing above
preg_replace('/[^\w]+/', '', substr($value, 0, 1));